# PDF API for Android

Tags: android, pdf

Someone knows about an API to edit PDF Files in Android? I need something that helps me with the zoom functionality and the rendering of big images.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a WebView and put the image in the html in that view. The WebView already has good zoom functionality.

Comment: Thnaks, but i already tried that. I forget to mention that one of my problems is need the text to be legible when i zoom in, that's why i need some api that work the text and images as separate objects.